# Isolation in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, isolation, multi-tenant

What isolation do I get when running an application in Google App Engine? It's clearly a pretty high density environment. Do I get my own threads? Or could it be that the thread I use to process my request may have just been used by another company?

I realise, if they have got security right, this shouldn't be a concern of mine. I am primarily interested to know how it works.

Comment: Your app runs in its own process, but accesses other resources via RPCs.  What are you actually trying to figure out?  Anyway, I hate used threads too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some details of the runtime are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html). In short, your application is run on some number of instances. Each instance consists of a dedicated process with its own sandboxed runtime environment (a Python interpreter or JRE). Runtimes aren't shared between apps.